# toupper() not working

Tags: c

Here I am checking if every char in the input array (inputText[]) matches at least one letter in the LETTERS array. But the toupper() function is not working for me. I am working on Linux mint and compiling with gcc.

```
do
{
    scanf(" %[^\n]s" , inputText );     
    printf("Input text supplied is: %s\n", inputText);
    int input_text_size = strlen(inputText) - 1;

    for(int i = 0; i <= input_text_size; i++)
    {
        toupper(inputText[i]);//NOT WORKING
        printf("toupper val = %c\n", inputText[i]);//TESTING 
        //testing every char against every element in LETTERS array 
        for(int j = 0; j <= 26; j++)
        {
            if(inputText[i] == LETTERS[j])
                flag--;
        }
    }

    if(flag != 0)
    {
       printf("Invalid input\n");
       printf("only letters and spaces can be entered\n");
       flag = input_text_size;
    }

}while(flag == 0);
```

Comment: `toupper` works out of place: `inputText[i] = toupper(inputText[i]);`

Comment: 2 questions in one isn't the way of asking. I answered the first question in comments, maybe now [edit] your question to show a [mcve]

Comment: Note that your format specifier `%[^\n]s` is a hybrid of two distinct formats `%[]` and `%s`.

Comment: You have set `int flag = input_text_size;` before you know the value of `input_text_size`. Have you a shadow variable of the same name, because the first usage seen is not in the scope of `int input_text_size = strlen(inputText) - 1;`

Comment: `int input_text_size = strlen(inputText) - 1;` The strlen function does not include the null terminator anyway, so dont subtract 0

Comment: It is very strange that you subtract 1 from the length and then have to adjust every time you use it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the manual page for `int toupper(int c)` more closely. the function prototype indicates that it returns the uppercased character.  In other words, it does not work on the data in-place.  Instead, as functions typically do, it returns a transformation of the data.

```
 for(i=0;i!=length;i++){
   string[i] = toupper(string[i]);
 }
```

Comment: Note that the standard prototype for [`toupper()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/toupper.html) is — `int
     toupper(int c);` — because it must accept every `char` value converted to `unsigned char` (0..255) and also EOF (negative, usually `-1`) and it can't do that if the argument is a `char`.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler.  I didn't bother to look it up and was just working from memory.

Comment: Strictly, if you could be dealing with accented characters in a single-byte code set and if plain `char` is a signed type, not an unsigned type, then you need `string[i] = toupper((unsigned char)string[i]);` — which also works if you're dealing with an unsigned plain `char` and if you aren't dealing with accented characters.  (None of this works with multi-byte or wide-character code sets — that's a whole separate bag'o'worms!)  I should have mentioned this in my previous comment too, I suppose.  Sorry to be working incrementally on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

since toupper is a function that returns a value you need to have a variable or have your array in that same index to receive the value toupper returns.

this should solve your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I think your answer would be better if you showed simple code to illustrate what you say.  If you add code inline, enclose it in back-ticks ```… `sample code` …```.  If you add the code as a display block, format it in the edit window as you want it to look, ignoring the preview, then select it and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it as code.  Now check the preview.  Don't use tabs in the code.  Do use copy'n'paste when writing bigger blocks of code.